# woocommerce blank page after clicking add to cart

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, woocommerce-offtopic

I am building a custom plugin based on woocommerce. As a part of this development I have added few custom fields to single product page at `woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_button` hook. These fields will be populated with some user meta data. I am able to see the custom fields on the page properly but problem arises when I try to submit the product to cart. As soon as I click on Add to Cart button I am seeing a blank page whose URL in address bar is same as that product page, may be the redirection to cart is no happening. When I go directly to the cart page to verify , I am able to see the added product in cart. Is there any solution for this blank page problem?

Comment: In wp-config.php file, define('WP_DEBUG',true); for error  checking.

Comment: I just did that and had this notice along with few warnings.Notice: The add_to_cart_redirect filter is deprecated since version ! Use woocommerce_add_to_cart_redirect instead. in XXXXXXXXXX/wp-includes/functions.php on line 3391

Comment: I think this is due to some functions deprecated in latest version of woocommerce. I have updated woocommerce and I have to sort out my theme overrides as well.

Comment: change the hook name from add_to_cart_redirect to woocommerce_add_to_cart_redirect.

Comment: the notice says to replace add_to_cart_redirect  with woocommerce_add_to_cart_redirect in wordpress functions.php. But i am not able to find add_to_cart_redirect filter in functions.php. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After so much research I figured it that the issue is due to a custom function I was trying to hook to the product page. All this while the custom function was wrongly hooked and I corrected it now.